# Escaping numbers in regex

Tags: regex

Is the following regex valid? And if so what does it do?

```
.*(.)(.)(.)(.)\4\3\2\1.*
```

Can't seem to find any info on escaping numbers, and why four (.) 's?

Abstracted from the Regex Sudoku/Crossword puzzle listed recently on [Slashdot](http://games.slashdot.org/story/13/02/13/2346253/can-you-do-the-regular-expression-crossword)

Comment: These are not digits but group numbers.

Comment: I did this one just the other week, it was so much fun!

Comment: @juergen d I had a suspicion something like this was the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks valid, yes, and simply means, "Match zero or more characters, followed by any four characters, followed by those same four characters, reveresed, followed by zero or more characters".

- `.*` = Zero or more occurrences of any character
- `(.)(.)(.)(.)` = Any four characters (and "capture" each one for later referece)
- `\4\3\2\1` = Match the fourth character captured, followed by the 3rd, the 2nd, the 1st
- `.*` = Zero or more occurrences of any character

These are all examples that would all match the RegEx:

- aweqwe12344321
- 12344321asdfas
- 12344321
- asdf12344321asdf

Comment: FYI, this has proved incredibly useful for Find/Replacing with Regex in Notepad++, ie Find "(.*)Smithe" Replace "\1Smith"

Answer (score 3):

It's not escaping the numbers; there are many regex libraries that use the `\#` notation to refer to the specific captured group.  That is, `\1` is the first captured group.

The `(.)` are each capture groups, so this would match something like

> abcddcba

Comment: Oh, I see.  The number refers to the group, a group being within a pair of brackets. So \4 is the 4th group, or 4th character in this case. This statement is merely looking for 4 characters and then the same 4 characters in reverse as your example illustrates?